# How do I move my h3 elements to be vertically aligned with span elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to align several h3 elements next to their corresponding span element, but i'm stuck. The end goal is to get something like this: [End goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK7hv.png), but instead it looks like this: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbZ7w.png).

I hoped the current code would work, but it seems like h3 elements will not inherit styling, and I am not able to add styling for each h3 element either. I have tried making a styling element for each h3 as well, but without success. I am hoping there is some css line that would make the current code work, if not a longer solution to the problem would also be very helpful.

The Grade returns a span element.

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.GradeCard {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 994px;
    height: 378px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 200px;

    background: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

/*Circle*/
.GradeCard span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.grade1 > *{
  left: 344px;
  top: 60px;
}

.grade2 > * {
  left: 344px;
  top: 139px;
}

.grade3 > * {
  left: 344px;
  top: 221px;
}

.grade4 > * {
  left: 344px;
  top: 295px;
}

.GradeCard .grade1, .grade2, .grade3, .grade4 h3 {
  color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  left: 394px;
}

.grade5 > * {
  left: 682px;
  top: 60px;
}

.grade6 > * {
  left: 682px;
  top: 139px;
}

.grade7 > * {
  left: 682px;
  top: 221px;
}

.grade8 > * {
  left: 682px;
  top: 295px;
}

.GradeCard .grade5, .grade6, .grade7, .grade8 h3 {
  color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  left: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Grade from './Grade'

//Grade returns a span element
function GradeCard() {
    return (
        <Card className="GradeCard">
            <Card.Body>
                <div className="grade1">
                    <Grade grade="A" />
                    <h3>Fagkunnskaper</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="grade2">
                    <Grade grade="C" />
                    <h3>Fagkunnskaper</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="grade3">
                    <Grade grade="B" />
                    <h3>Fagkunnskaper</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="grade4">
                    <Grade grade="D" />
                </div>
                <div className="grade5">
                    <Grade grade="E" />
                </div>
                <div className="grade6">
                    <Grade grade="F" />
                </div>
                <div className="grade7">
                    <Grade grade="A" />
                </div>
                <div className="grade8">
                    <Grade grade="B" />
                </div>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default GradeCard;
```

I'm new to stack overflow, so please tell me if something is missing in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your wrapper (grade1, grade2 and so on) to display:flex; should do the trick

```
div[class^=grade] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I've made a quick [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DrQuarzZz/pen/zYrbjbO) for you to look at.

P.S. Also be careful with all of the absolute positioning and absolut px values. That's not the proper way to do it and will probably end up not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not try to add a different class for everything, check if there is pattern and a class to represent the pattern
2. can't you use any utility library like bootstrap that helps in layouting
3. use flex layout to easily layout content

```
// row containing two grades
HTML:
<div class="row">

// grade 1
<div class="grade">
<Grade grade="Z" />
<h3>z-grade</h3>

// grade 2
<div class="grade">
<Grade grade="Y" />
<h3>y-grade</h3>
</div>
</div>
// repeat the structure

CSS:
.row {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row; // this will be the default value anyway
justify-content: space-between
}
.grade {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this style for your parents of heading levels

```css
.GradeCard div[class*=grade]{
display : flex;
item-align : center ;
}
```